# Analytic continuation of a logarithm function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-continuation

What is the analytic continuation of
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{z^n}n, \text{ where |z| < 1} $$

For real values of $z$, this function of course corresponds to the Taylor expansion of log(1-x). However, the complex logarithm function is multi-valued - so how do we choose an
analytic continuation of $f(x)$ for $|z| > 1$, since the analytic continuation is supposed unique?
Do we simply take the principial branch of the complex log function?

Comment: Yes, it is $Log (1-z)$ for $z \in \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ where Log is the principal branch.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1756293)

Comment: Why is it the principial branch? I looked at the linked answer but it doesn't really answer it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You probably mean $z \in \mathbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$. The analytic continuation of $f$ to $\mathbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$ is unique, but there's nothing special about $[1, \infty)$, there's also a unique analytic continuation of $f$ to, say, $\mathbb C \setminus [1, 1 + i \infty)$.

Comment: When it exists the analytic continuation of a power series at $a$ to a connected open containing $a$ is unique. Here the analytic continuation to $\Bbb{C}-1$ doesn't exist, it exists for any simply connected open  $\subset \Bbb{C}-1$ containing $0$ and there it is unique. To understand the continuations of the continuations we need the concept of analytic continuation along a curve (the continuation of $\log z$ along the counterclockwise unit circle sends $\log z$ to $\log z+2i\pi$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic continuation is not as universally applicable as we might sometimes want.  The identity theorem says that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic on a open connected domain $D$ and agree on an open subset of $D$ (or even on a set of points that has am accumulation point in $D$) then $f=g$ throughout $D$.  But notice that $f$ and $g$ must first both be analytic on $D$.  You cannot always guarantee that you can extend $f$ from a smaller to larger domain unless you first know such an extension will work.

An example is as follows.  We know one version of $\log z$ can be defined that is analytic on the domain
\begin{align}
D_1 = \{ z: 1 < |z| < 3, |\arg(z)| > \pi/8\}.
\end{align}
Using a power series centred at $z = 2$ we can create a second function analytic in the disc $D_2 = \{z: |z-2| < 2\}$ and which agrees with our $\log z$ on the part of $D_1 \cap D_2$ for which $\Im z > 0$.  But this will not then agree with our  $\log z$ on the intersection $D_1 \cap D_2$ where $\Im z < 0$.  That is because there is no analytic function on a domain that circles the origin and at the same time matches our $\log z$ throughout $D_1$.  In this example the identity theorem cannot be used as such an extension does not exist.
[[image: Picture of two domains <span class=]$D_1$ and $D_2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR0Zr.png)

Turning to your example, you can extend your power series into a larger domain, but you may end up with different branches depending on how your extension progresses around the singularity, which in your case is at $z=1$.  But as soon as you try to make your extension circle back to the first domain, the identity theorem ceased to apply.